# javascript how to cycle through characters of my string so it looks like a marquee using just javascript

Tags: javascript, time, intervals

how to cycle through characters of my string so it looks like a marquee using just javascript. I am a beginner in javascript and stuck on how I would repeat this code so it keeps cycling through all of the characters in the string so it looks like it is a text feed.

```
<br>
<button onclick="clearTimeout(myVar)">Stop</button>
<br>
<br>
<p id="iop"></p>
<br>
<br>
<script>
    var myVar = setInterval(change, 1000);

    function change() {
    var str= "My Javascript marquee";
    var num = 1;
    var result = str.substr(num) + str.substr(0, num);
    document.getElementById("iop").innerHTML = result;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: A marquee? Like the old HTML marquee?

Comment: How would `"My Javascript marquee"` look like after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close to make it working:

```
var myVar = setInterval(change, 1000);

var str = "My Javascript marquee";

function change() {
    var num = 1;
    var result = str.substr(num) + str.substr(0, num);
    document.getElementById("iop").innerHTML = result;
    str = result;
}
```

The initial string must be initialized outside the `change()` function.

Otherwise the function will operate always on the same initial string (giving always the same result).

Finally, once you have computed the "shifted" string you have to save it `str = result;` in order to let it be the string that will be processed at the next iteration.

Here is the **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3myq3yx7/)**